# Reducing for loops to get group members of each group from salesforce org in apex handler

Tags: list, dictionary, set, salesforce, apex

So I am a bit stumped at the moment... I had desired functionality that involved 4 layered for loops, this gave me the CPU timeout error with apex.

What I am trying to do is: Get a map of all groups in a salesforce Org, where the key is the group Id. Then get all all group members, then find what group members belong to each group and add to a list so I can get the size of the group by the group members, but am having trouble finding a way to do this with maps that prevents nested for loops...

I feel 2 layered for loop is almost necessary?

After I do this, I need to check which all invited attendees of a salesforce event (Event Relations) with the list of group members for a group I just found, and if all are found in attendees, then add the group as an attendee for filtering on the javascript side.

But I might be able to figure out the attendee bit if I could figure out getting the group members per each group in an efficient way.

Does anyone have any suggestions using Maps, sets, and or lists to go about doing this? Or any different approach to get the group members for each group?

Thank you in advance! (P.S. Working in Apex for salesforce development).

This is kind of what I have so far. The first loop did have nested loops, I altered a bit, but my alterations don't exactly work in fixing the issue. **also these sets of for loops are already inside a for loop looping through all events.

```
for(Integer x = 0; x < groupMemberList.size(); x++){
                    if(groupMap.containsKey(groupMemberList[x].GroupId)){
                        collectMembers.add(groupMemberList[x])
                    }   
                    if(attendeeMap.containsKey(groupMemberList[x].UserOrGroupId)){
                        groupMembersInEvent.add(groupMemberList[x].UserOrGroupId);
                    }
                }
                    for(Integer x = 0; x < relations.size(); x++){
                        for(Id memId : collectMembers){
                            if(relations[x].attendeeId == memId){
                                groupMembersInEvent.add(memId);
                            }
                        }
                        if(groupMembersInEvent.size() == collectMembers.size()){
                            attendee = new attendeeInfo();
                            //Another loop to loop through groups to get name for this group id? Is it necessary?
                            attendee.attendeeName = 'group';
                            attendee.attendeeId = uniqueGroupId;
                            relations.add(attendee);
                        }
                    }
                    groupMembersInEvent = new List<Id>();
                    collectMembers = new List<Id>();
                }
```

Comment: Can you post what did you try so far?

Comment: I edited with a bit of code from my loops